# Get Values from table called with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I want to do is get values from my payments table and make a sum

But in my return I get this issue in return View(**model**); :

> Argument type models.Payments is not assignable to model type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I get this error because I don't assign correct model in my View

Comment: Where are you getting this error ?

Comment: You are passing a single object of the Payments class.  Is your razor view strongly typed to a single instance or a collection ?

Comment: I getting error on `return View(model);`  NOTE: I update my view

Comment: Where is the view code ?

Comment: @Shyju in my question

Comment: @Shyju do you see it?

Comment: Your view expects `@model IEnumerable<EarningsViewModel>` but you method is returning a model of type `Payments`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your razor view is strongly typed to a collection of EarningsViewModel. But from your action method, you are passing a single object of `Payments` class. So you are getting this error !

Ideally you should create a new view model for this specific view.

```
public class ClientPaymentInfo
{
  public string ClientName { set;get;}
  public List<PaymentInfoVm> Payments { set;get;}
  public ClientPaymentInfo()
  {
    Payments = new List<PaymentInfoVm>();
  }
}
public class PaymentInfoVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string PaymentNumber { set;get;}
  public decimal Amount { set;get;}
}
```

Now you should update your razor view to be strongly typed to that type.

```
@model ClientPaymentInfo
<h2>Payments of @Model.ClientName</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.Payments)
{
  <p>@item.Amount</p>
  <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
  </p>

}
<p>Total : @Model.Payments.Sum(s=>S.Amount)
```

So your action method will be

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  var vm= new ClientPaymentInfo { ClientName = "Hard coded Client Name"};

  vm.Payments = db.PaymentsList.Where(x => x.ClientsId == id)
                .Select(d=>new PaymentInfoVm { 
                            Id=d.Id,
                            Amount=d.Amount, 
                            PaymentNumber=d.Paymentnumber}).ToList();
  return View(vm);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sending a model of a different type, so your view is specting a list of `EarningsViewModel`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.ViewModels.EarningsViewModel>
```

And you are passing a `Payments` object.